# Given two points on a 2D grid, how many paths of length N connects them?

Tags: combinatorics

The paths are not required to be monotonic, and they may self-intersect. This sounds like a difficult question, so what I am really asking is if this problem has a name, if it is NP-hard and if there is some upper bound. I assume the grid to be infinitely large.

The image below shows some example paths for two points, $A$, $B$, but I am not asking about these points specifically. The paths have length $N=7$, $N=9$ and $N=11$.

[image]

Comment: The number of *shortest* paths that connects them is given by $\frac{((x_2-x_1)+(y_2-y_1))!}{(x_2-x_1)!(y_2-y_1)!}$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the points. I'm not sure about the number of paths for any length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the two points be $A(a,b)$ and $B(a+r,b+u)$. Note that $r$ and $u$ represent the *net* moves along the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively required to reach point B from point A.

**Case $1$:**  If $|r|+|u|=N$, then the paths have to be monotonic and the answer is simply $$N\choose |r|$$

**Case $2$:** If $|r|+|u|>N$, then there aren't  enough moves and the answer is $0$.

**Case $3$: $|r|+|u|\lt N$**

Now for the harder part. I'll write $|r|+|u|+2x=N$. The $2x$ here represents the extra moves needed. Notice that the  number of extra moves will be always be even as with every additional left move, we need a right move and with every additional down move, we need an up move.

Now, define $P_1$ to be the number of extra pairs $\boxed{LR}$ (one left and one right move) and similarly $P_2$ to be the number of extra pairs $\boxed{DU}$(one down and one up move). Clearly, $P_1+P_2=x$, and $P_1$ and $P_2$ can range from $0$ to $x$ giving us a total of $x+1$ possibilities. Furthermore, it's not hard to check that for a fixed $P_1$, the total number of $$\text{Right moves is} \ (|r|+P_1) \\ \text{Left moves is} \ (P_1) \\ \text{Up moves is} \ (|u|+x-P_1) \\ \text{Down moves is} \ (x-P_1) $$ Given all this, the only thing that remains is to take care of the order of moves, which is equivalent to permuting the stated number of $R’s, L’s, U’s$ and $D’s$. Summing the possibilities fetches the answer.

In the sum below, the first factor decides where the $R’s$ go, the second factor decides where the $L’s$ go in the remaining places, and the third factor decides where the $U’s$ go, after which the $D’s$ are already taken care of.
$$\sum_{P_1=0}^x {N\choose {|r|+P_1}} {{N-(|r|+P_1)}\choose{P_1}} {{N-(|r|+2P_1)}\choose{|u|+x-P_1}}
\\ =\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{N-|r|-|u|}{2}} {N\choose {|r|+k}} {{N-(|r|+k)}\choose{k}} {{N-(|r|+2k)}\choose{\frac{N+|u|-|r|}{2}-k}} $$ A monstrosity indeed.

Comment: Duude, I was sitting on the bus, thinking how to solve this problem. I came up with the same solution as you in my head. Looks like I was beaten :D. Good job anyway. The problem looks much harder than it is on the first glance

Comment: Perhaps it would be great to add a bit of explanation to the combinations expression you have constructed, and explicitly state that there are 0 paths for the case when N-r-u is not divisible by 2.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins That’s great. I added an explanation for the sum. As for the other thing, from my definition of $x$, $N-r-u=2x$ which is always divisible by $2$. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is just an idea, so correct me if I am wrong

Say we need to get to a point B($n_1,n_2$) from A($0,0$), in $N$ steps.

Let $x_i$ denote a move in the $x$ direction (its value can be $1$ or $-1$ depending on right or left.)
Similarly define a variable $y_i$.

Now,

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+....x_r=n_1........(1)$$

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+.....y_{N-r}=n_2.......(2)$$

So possible solutions for (1) can be found by:

=coefficient of $x^{n_1}$ in $(x^1+x^{-1})^r$ =$A(r)$

Similarly, no. of possible solutions for (2):

=coeff. of $x^{n_2}$ in $(x^1+x^{-1})^{N-r}$ = $B(r)$

So the total possible combinations are;

=$$\sum_{r=0}^N A(r) \times B(r) $$

If the functions of $A(r)$ and $B(r)$ are found, then I think you can get a nice closed form.

Comment: Trying it for a simple case like n1 = 2, n2 = 0 and N = 4 I seem to get 6 possible paths. Counting them, I think the correct answer is 16. Maybe the method does not consider that interchanging the order of the x-hoppings and y-hoppings gives different paths. Adding a factor of N-r combinations of N gives the correct answer in this case.